# How to get access to two-level nested variable?

Tags: vue.js

There is pretty clear how to get access to variable in `data`. But how to do it, if it have 2-level nesting:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    users :
        {
        foo : {
        name : "aa"
      }
    }
  }
})
```

How to display: `name` ?

https://jsfiddle.net/n1ewmfs5/

Comment: your jsfiddle works, when you remove ["first"]. However it looks like you want to have an array of users. this should then be users:[{...},{..}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure If I really understand the question but here you have two examples (taken form your jsfiddle) that access "name" from the `users` object you have provided.

```
<p>{{users['foo']['name']}}</p>
```

or you can

```
<p>{{users.foo.name}}</p>
```

But you maybe want to have an array of users?

Answer (score 0):

What is the issue with that . It is just a json.

Json can be access by `.` symbol .

if you have {a:{b:{c:'name'}}}

you can access a.b.c or a['b']['c']

check the jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/himmsharma99/ctj4sm7f/

```
`<div id="app">
  <p>{{users['foo']['name'] }}</p>

  <div >
  <p>{{users.foo.name }}</p>
</div>`
```